# What is a residual predicate?

Tags: sql-server, terminology

Although I was able to find the definition of predicates online at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189523.aspx):

> Is an expression that evaluates to
> TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN. Predicates
> are used in the search condition of
> WHERE clauses and HAVING clauses, the
> join conditions of FROM clauses, and
> other constructs where a Boolean value
> is required.

I have been unable to find the definition of what a *residual* predicate is. What is a residual predicate?

Comment: See [Probe Residual vs Join Predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237340/probe-residual-vs-join-predicate) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A residual predicate is one that has an hidden extra cost because the predicate has to be tested again on every combination of rows that is fetched.

See [Probe Residual when you have a Hash Match – a hidden cost in execution plans](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2011/03/22/probe-residual-when-you-have-a-hash-match-a-hidden-cost-in-execution-plans/) by Rob Farley.